# Deserializing JSON List

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list

I'm trying to deserialize some Json using the JsonConvert. The example in JSON that I want to handle is:

```
 2  {
 3    'Name': 'Product 1',
 4    'ExpiryDate': '2000-12-29T00:00Z',
 5    'Price': 99.95,
 6    'Sizes':{ 'Tall': 30
                'ExtraTall':40
              }
 7  },
 8  {
 9    'Name': 'Product 2',
10    'ExpiryDate': '2009-07-31T00:00Z',
11    'Price': 12.50,
12    'Sizes': null
13  }
```

I already tried some stuff like:

```
var handlerLocal= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Dictionary <string,Dictionary<string,string>>>(z);
```

Till now I'm only handling simple lists using this:

```
var handlerLocal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FriendsHandler>(z);
```

FriendHandler works like a model. But in this new case I have a List inside a List and that is killing me.

Anyone can help me?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

In general with `JSON.net` you can just write a object that matches what you're parsing correctly and then use DeserializeObject as you have.

In this case the JSON you have provided is invalid. It would be a dictionary in the case that it looked like this:

```
{'thing1': {
    'Name': 'Product 1',
    'ExpiryDate': '2000-12-29T00:00Z',
    'Price': 99.95,
    'Sizes':{ 'Tall': 30
                'ExtraTall':40
              }
  },
  'thing2': {
    'Name': 'Product 2',
    'ExpiryDate': '2009-07-31T00:00Z',
    'Price': 12.50,
    'Sizes': null
  }}
```

I think it should be an array, which means it should be surrounded by `[]`.

To parse this, just do this:

```
var handlerLocal = JArray.Parse(z).ToObject<List<FriendsHandler>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to deserialise JSON, I find it best to use [Json2Sharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) to create classes to contain data, however the JSON you've provided is invalid so it's not possible to create a class from this.

If you could find some valid JSON to use, this tool will handle the rest for you.

Comment: Or "Paste JSON as Classes" in VS 2013 or better.

Comment: Really? I'm on VS2015, and I've never even heard of this function. I guess I haven't spent a lot of time digging through the tools. Thanks for the heads up on this one.

Comment: `Edit->Paste Special->Paste JSON as Classes`

Comment: This is gold. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> Sizes { get; set; }
}
```

Get your JSON

```
var productsJson = << Call some repo that returns json string >>
```

Then call

```
var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(productsJson);
```

NOTE: You will need to make your JSON valid first, it is syntactically incorrect at the moment

******EDIT*******

The question needs updating (see comments), your models would look like this

```
public class Self
{
    public string DeviceID { get; set; }
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string RoomID { get; set; }
    public string Room { get; set; }
}

public class Friend
{
    public string IdUser { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Self Self { get; set; }
    public List<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(productsJson);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob for the answer. And sorry for the JSON because I copied it from another place and just edited to fit my personal problem. The thing is I already have the model and I think it is correct but the response is {
    "self": {
        "deviceID": "8",
        "timeStamp": "Feb 18, 2016 16:01:47",
        
    },
    "friends": [
        {
            "idUser": "4",
            "name": "John",         
            "location": {
                "roomID": "562",
                "room": "B3.39A",
                
            }
        }
    ]
}   I have and array inside the response.

Comment: Can you please update the question with the actual JSON and the actual model that you have? Otherwise its impossible to help